# Form Radio not working

Tags: html, css

http://caveo.sg/gama/motor-insurance-2.php

The radio button not working. Seems like the CSS problem but i cannot get a solution.

in the HTML code as follows:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="gender1"/>Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="gender2"/>Female
```

in CSS, code:

```
input,
textarea {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  outline: none !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u must remove the   -webkit-appearance: none;

-webkit-apperance = Make a element look like a button or something

Comment: What's the reason? I tried removing n it works on safari n chrome but not Mozilla Firefox. In Mozilla, radio buttons appear but cannot be selected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you use a label. Remove the label and it will works :)
You can also use a label, but use it for one input type(radiobutton.) When you use it for a group it doens't work.

(This problem can be for Firefox only)

Comment: Label? My text are not in label tag... What do u mean I'm using label?

Comment: This is your code on the website:    `<label class="name"> (radio buttons) </label>`    Remove the <label>